# Disable smart accents on french keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using a french keyboard on Windows 10, and as someone that regularly formats code in markdown (using backticks, like on SE), I am trying to find a way to disable the "smart" accents feature, or whatever the name of the following feature is.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> (key combination for backtick, as you can see [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/French_pc_keyboard.svg)), the backtick will *not* be written yet; I have to press any key again so that it does get written (I currently press space). The purpose of this feature is to be able to apply accents to any letter, for example if press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> and then <kbd>u</kbd> then I will get `ù`. I'm guessing this is useful for many people, but the french keyboard already has keys for the most useful accented letters and this behavior is very annoying.

Is there any way I could disable it, so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> the backtick gets immediately written ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: this allows to produce a

```
`
```

with just one keystroke of <kbd>²</kbd>, using Autohotkey:

```
+²::
Send ²
Return

$²::
Send ``
Send {space}
Return
```

To get `²`, just press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>²</kbd>

Comment: Thanks ! so I guess the trick was to use `Send \`\``.. simple but solves it !

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoHotkey.  The following command would send a backtick when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>.

```
^!7::`
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however I when I tried this I was surprised to discover that .. the behavior persists. Even if I remap it to another key combination, or try using `Send` or `SendRaw`, the same problem arises.

Comment: @TrakJohnson me too...